# TestRestTemplate HTTP Requests that return as Array/Stream?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using TestRestTemplate I am trying to create tests. Some of my methods return streamed object of arrays but I'm not sure how to retrieve the body:

Container.java

```
public class SomeObject implements Serializable
{
    private int index;
    public SomeObject(int i) { index = i; }
    public String getIndex() { return index; }
}
```

In Tester.java:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    ResponseEntity<SomeObject[]> objects = this.testRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/test", <What goes here?>);
}
```

In Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> func()
{
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = response -> {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            SomeObject obj = new SomeObject(i);
            response.write(<What goes here?>);
            response.flush();
        }
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
this.testRestTemplate.postForEntity(URL, HTTP_ENTITY, SomeObject[].class, PARAMS);
```

Comment: I don't believe this actually works for streamed arrays. I've updated the post with a testable example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StreamingResponseBody as your type then recreate your dto from the byte stream.

In the controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> func() throws IOException {

    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject(1337);
    // set up object

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    os.writeObject(obj);
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = responseStream -> {

        int numberOfBytesToWrite;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            responseStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
        }

        is.close();
    };

    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(responseBody);
}
```

In the test:

```java
@Test
void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> result = this.testRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/test", StreamingResponseBody.class);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Objects.requireNonNull(result.getBody()).writeTo(baos);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    SomeObject object = (SomeObject) is.readObject();
    is.close();

    System.out.println(object.getIndex());
}
```

Alternatively you can SomeObject to a json string and simplify the whole toByteArray conversion.

Comment: Very solid base for an answer. Could you also respond to the other parts of the bounty premise as well please? Ex: How to stream JSON, are getters/setters required, is empty constructor required, what about streaming one very large object, etc. I'm just looking for things about streaming and testing the streamed data.